# Sencha Touch tabPanel using dynamic JSON data

Tags: tabs, sencha-touch, extjs

In my application the first page shows a tabPanel at the bottom. But number of tabs, their labels and icons are dynamic content coming from a json request. I am wondering how to do it. Here is what i tried.

```
TMDemo = new Ext.Application({
name: 'TMDemo',
launch: function(){
    this.views.mainTabBar = new this.views.MainTabBar();

}
```

});

```
TMDemo.views.MainTabBar = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel,{
fullscreen: true,
 tabBar:{
    dock:'bottom',
    layout:{
        pack:'center'
    }
 },
 addItems: function(){
        this.add(addItemsBasedOnJsonData());
        this.doLayout(); // important
},
listeners: {
    beforerender:function(){
        Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: 'app/data/tabbar.json',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        callback: function(result) {
         console.log("Inside callback");    
         TMDemo.tabBarData = result;                              
        }
    });
}
    render: function(){
        console.log("Inside render");
        this.addItems();
    }
}
```

});

Here the tabbar data is coming from tabbar.json (dummy data actual will be some URL). I am adding items to this tabpanel through addItemsBasedOnJsonData() function which will create the tab items and returns the array.
But the problem is render event always fire first then the JSON request callback, so no jsondata available to create tabs dynamically.
Please guide me to a right direction. Whether this approach is right. Can i have any example to look for.

Tarun

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
callback: function(result) {
         console.log("Inside callback");    
         TMDemo.tabBarData = result;
         TMDemo.views.mainTabBar.add(TMDemo.views.mainTabBar.addItemsBasedOnJsonData());

 }
```

Comment: I tried this with a doLayout call after adding the items. The tabbar data is available but the tabs are not rendered correctly, i mean the css is messed up.

Comment: callback: function(result) {
       console.log("Inside callback"); 
    TMDemo.tabBarData = result;
    TMDemo.views.mainTabBar.add(TMDemo.views.mainTabBar.addItemsBasedOnJsonData());
    TMDemo.views.mainTabBar.doLayout();                   
            }

Comment: I tried the doComponentLayout also but this also has the same effect and also doesn't show the first tab content.

Comment: Its weird..try to actually create the whole TabPanel inside the callback...you shouldn't have to do this though. Can you update your question with your Json Data and the addItemsBasedOnJsonData method?

Comment: Basically whenever i am calling add item from callbak function the tabs are not rendered correctly. The tab bar element height is rendered as 1px